# Calculate The Digit Sum

Tags: code-golf, math, number

Your task is to get two numbers, and output the digit sum of them. We'll define digit sum as the following:

- take the **decimal** (base 10) digits of each of them, and pad with 0s the shortest number (e.g. [1,9], [0, 7])
- sum the digits as vectors (e.g. [1, 16])
- convert the number back from base 19, and output it (e.g. 1*19+16=35)

## Input

You can take the input as two numbers, as a list containing both of them or in any other reasonable format (like an array of digits). You can assume the shortest number is padded with zeros so it fits the length of the longer one

## Output

You can output the digit sum in any reasonable format.

## Test cases

```
1, 2 -> 3
5, 10 -> 24
42, 32 -> 137
15717, 51358 -> 826819
1000, 1 -> 6860
```

explanation of 5, 10: the digits of these are [0, 5] and [1, 0]. Their sum is [1, 5], which when converted from base 19 results in 24.

## Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins, good luck!

Comment: [Post in sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18840)

Comment: Can we take the input digit lists in reverse?

Comment: i have a question, why base 19? is it a random specific or it has a mathematical meaning who i don't get?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I'm not OP, but in a comment on the sandbox post (s)he mentions: ["_It's the smallest base for which the sum of any two digits in base 10 fit in_"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/18840#comment67987_18840).

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
19#.+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy9CsIwAIT3PMVhwSLWmDRN/6CLgpM4uDppm9ZIaKCNFZ@@inG44bv7uMe8oGGHqkSICAzlNxuK/fl4mHkR0PV2XhFy2lHUtp/U4OAsGt1pB6NHN6LVw@giXI2xL9Xg9sbwNGokbUVxKdGBs2VAdT8Rouq7hUCFFhyxxzjxzCB9wUX2a5IY4u/kcZrzwnsy4xkkFzL3W5qn7P/AGPj8AQ)

- `19#.` convert the following to base 19...
- `+/` elementwise sum of the input digit lists.

Comment: You can take a digit list as an input.

Comment: Thanks, not much content at this point though.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḅ19S
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of digits which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlZDy@D///9HG@pYxuooRJvHAgA)**

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org), 30 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:int(a,19)+int(b,19)
```

An unnamed function accepting two strings of (base ten) digit characters which returns an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsMgEETP7VfsbV0qRWMlaSB/0otSpIHGiOQSQr7dumkuu29mWGbTunzmaLqUSxhe5esm/3bgpO/HuAgn9ZNuTJ6phDnXDDyMEYRAjRKwQZIg0DJr9RePhpU5I21b3bJhtbHd6Smljgsk6q@XlLkEg9h2CdtOMNSJ99o3OX4DvIRwbCIqPw)**

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

-1 thanks to Command Master.

```
+19β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f29Dy3Kb//6MNdUx1zHUMdcxjuaJNgbQxkG8RCwA)

Comment: [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f29Dy3Kb//6MNdExjuaINdQxiAQ)

Comment: `+` vectorizes!? I was an idiot.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of digit arrays.

```
ì19
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=7DE5&input=WwpbMSwwLDAsMF0KWzFdCl0)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:a+b and a%10+b%10+19*f(a/10,b/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NisMwDEb3PoUIDLUnasdymp8W0ouUWdikYQyJY2wz0NOndjZCenr6kH@nv82pfZ/HRa9m0qDR3HVtQLsJ9BfJ2pRCt@@Z6x@SaHIRu139FhLEd2Rs3gIs1r3AugIuMU3W3RkAz1kCc1KEEVbt@etfL3i4l@gXm/jp/DgJkdWQjfnw8@CDdak8gmWPAaF6VnVMgYdxzGmirn6rnRAUnB/QsBaBZGnVlV0VQnNwanpGbU89QktNOxQ2qG6gGyMpZb4ppBs6@QE)

Recursive function that sums each digit pair and convert them to base 19.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Tr[#~FromDigits~19&/@#]&
```

Unnamed function taking as input a list that contains two lists of digits. The main point here is that converting to base 19 first and then adding means that padding on the left is unnecessary.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6QoWrnOrSg/1yUzPbOkuM7QUk3fQTlW7X9AUWZeiUNadLVCtaGOqY65jqGOea2CjkK1KZBlDBSxqFWojf0PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
Total@PadLeft@#~FromDigits~19&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyS/JDHHISAxxSc1rcRBuc6tKD/XJTM9s6S4ztBS7X9AUWZeiYJDerRnXklqemoRRMqh2lDHqDaWC5esqY6hAR5pEyMdY3zaDU3NDc11FEwNjU0t8CkzMDDQMayN/f8fAA)

Takes input as list of digits as @my pronoun is monicareinstate suggested and saved 13 bytes (IntegerDigits)

-1 byte @LegionMammal978

Comment: I think you can take two lists of digits as input.

Comment: -1 byte: `Total@PadLeft@IntegerDigits@#~FromDigits~19&`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>67</s></sup> 65 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mitchell Spector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59825/mitchell-spector)!!!

```c
s;m;f(a,b){for(s=m=1;a+b;a/=10,b/=10,m*=19)s+=(a%10+b%10)*m;s--;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/BjoMgEIbvfYpJExMoYwparQ3LvkjXA2jdeIBuZE9rfHZ3oOXwz8D/zeRnKL@HYd@j9npiFh1fp@fCovFGaSuctmejJLqs/mTUjUdhmC2UFI6En7yOZam33ds5ML4e5vAL9t6DgVUhNAiXCkE1V3WlIqXcdEbcC0meRKipNqpuOrq@gccLqBGqC73WNN5Vbadu2HZt2pJyJjAYqcNHnP8eT/oBP787srgWIlAkoJPIhRYScg89OhKus/OzkDexYzEiFCOUn0lZMfKvcETINLisC1Kq0BsTaXQ7bPs/)

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY/BjoMgEIbvfYpJExMoYwparQ3LvkjXA2jdeIBuZE9rfHZ3oOXwz8D/zeRnKL@HYd@j9npiFh1fp@fCovFGaSuctmejJLqs/mTUjUdhmC2UFI6En7yOZam33ds5ML4e5vAL9t6DgVUhNAiXCkE1V3WlIqXcdEbcC0meRKipNqpuOrq@gccLqBGqC73WNN5Vbadu2HZt2pJyJjAYqcNHnP8eT/oBP787srgWIlAkoJPIhRYScg89OhKus/OzkDexYzEiFCOUn0lZMfKvcETINLisC1Kq0BsTaXQ7bPs/)

Comment: @MitchellSpector Nice, homogeneous init with a tweak at the end to make it the return value - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>54</s> <s>53</s></sup> 19 bytes

```bash
echo $[19#$1+19#$2]
```

[Try the test cases online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwFET3/xRDzK6o@amhCrU73XoAcRHbYATbSFVsTx9r0M0s5vFmzvbhY22fqO59uPS2RVmK3WEvoqt9gDzyZiY5@6Y@xQkQ1b4NDV7ZgJ9C9PbXm0PvbIMBIwFNmAJIG/MOQg6QI7YVROoXy/9bAknoXGRoMmBFK41cE5uCCxjOzZpYKQWmDw)

---

The input numbers are passed as two arguments.

Output is on stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 5 bytes

**Solution:**

```
19/+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/39BSX1tfw1DBAAStwaSCoeb//wA)

**Explanation:**

Takes input as two lists of digits. Assumes the shorter number is padded with 0s.

```
19/+/ / the solution
   +/ / sum
19/   / decode from base 19
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＩΣＥ²⍘Ｓ¹⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDSEfBKbE4NbgEKJWu4ZlXUFoCZWvqKBhaaoKA9f//hqbmhuYKpobGphb/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as two strings. Explanation:

```
    ⍘Ｓ¹⁹    Convert the input from base 19
  Ｅ²        Repeated twice
ＩΣ          Summed and output in decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Takes input as two lists of digits. Assumes the shorter number is padded with 0's.

```
siR19
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzgzyNDy//9oQx1THXMdQx3zWJ1oUyBtDORbxAIA)

```
siR19
  R       (Right-) Map each digit array of the input to:
 i 19     The digit array converted from base 19
s         Take the sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 47 bytes

```
?[0q]sZ[sydsxly+0=ZlxA~rlyA~4R+_3Rlfx19*+]dsfxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@2qAwtjgqurgypbgip1LbwDYqp8Kxriin0rHOJEg73jgoJ63C0FJLOzalOK2i4P9/Q1NzQ3MFU0NjUwsuAA)

[Or verify all the test cases online.](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoJAGAbv/1N8LJ2SalcTC7LoUNegYyJh7prBquUWrRC9uiUhXeYwMHNKTN6myR1LXOvqXCcFFgu22W1Zu4r4LTaHyDTSWN04PDxou37Xulm/p3vn6O11ZsV86MTSZPbafiOiNC8qiYdj@x3RM79ohVolEvpSKgJk9QWg0rzCqAQbdB7hEuzvf5LhBZlilGE86YddX6pWwCUfgtPUheeS8AMRwBeePyPBOYegDw)

Input is on stdin (the two numbers on one line, separated by a space).

Output is on stdout.

---

This program makes use of a nice facility in `dc`, where the single-character command `~` will compute **both** the quotient and the remainder in a division operation.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 43 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b)=>a+b&&a%10+b%10+19*f(a/10|0,b/10|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhBDoIwEADvvoIDklYW3AUb9AAfaRrYKhgNUiLGC/J2tF5mMnPnN0/n5218JZZt2yeDu7Tr2pWCwcqy4thGEW8JY@tBp10neE/4QbB/yfXshsn1bdq7q9CaIDOgFRD@dMgg90mqoAIU5eroCxGBjEkfPIq6rBodzrVGs4A3mcUESRWEcyf8Bb/k0ki5Wb8)

Comment: But `(a,b)=>(p=parseInt)(a,19)+p(b,19)` is only 33 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 40 bytes

```java
a->b->a.valueOf(""+a,19)+a.valueOf(b,19)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBPa8JAEMXvfopBEJK6hqwarFpzLPRQevAoHiYmkbVxE3YnAZF89nSi8R89DLvvN7NvH3PACkeH@LdRxyI3BAfWXkkq896WvX8sLfWOVK7b5i5Da@EblYZzD6Aoo0ztwBISH1WuYjhyz1mTUXq/2QKavXUvowCfnc/Hl6ZknxhxB9dx0fEwhHTV4CiMRiF6FWZl8pM6/f4QhZy7wweKWt0sL@ZK02bLH1JiycKq@xLgDHIuYAa1eAAB42cdCJD@M5iOBUxeRmQwkzMBgZwE7y/c931@fUP1NUuaG3AqNJcwi2sk956IkwJywhZv/K2A6CYkC5PYMiMmqYdFkZ0cdLsLLyByl53J@mQpOXp5SV7BuyPezyAWMIgXXAPdF4BsfLPrntW9turmDw)

Takes input as `a:Integer` and `b:String`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 75 bytes

```php
for($n=strlen($a=$argv[1]);$n--;)$r+=($a[$i]+$argv[2][$i++])*19**$n;echo$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFTybItLinJS8zRUEm1VEovSy6INYzWtVfJ0da01VYq0bYHi0SqZsdoQOaNYIEdbO1ZTy9BSS0slzzo1OSNfpcj6////Jkb/jY0A)

As often, getting arguments and dollars makes PHP the longest answer so far :D still i'm content with this

Takes input as strings already padded with zeroes

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.sum{|x|x.to_i 19}}
```

Accepts an array of two strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczNDkNAHATw@z7FxAXpkv1jfRx4kaZpaCkJJV1SDZ5dbXub/DIzr6n47FW6O1m@5K6aumWd19kd@2sDSrZtf9dNW8KakeJRjsq91X032AzIOYoDZ1cNbTPChJPBPHyYRoXqnP/dMjlM@6IPFU4wdMs4QsHK530nDk@LzyQHCR29gAUeh/9z8iNGMqKIQ5IvY22xF8aUMBJCHBstYRyKLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
~ḃ₁₉ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/XDXznIlBV07BaVyeyD7UduGR01ND3d11j7cOuF/3cMdzY@aGh81dQJ52v//RytEG@oYxeooRJvqGBqAaBMjHWOwgKGpuaG5jqmhsakFmGtgYKBjGKsQCwA)

Takes input as a digit list, but the testing header converts from single integers for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
z+19Ad
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLqrQNLR1TIByo2ILt0YY6pjrmOoY65rFc0aZA2hjIt4iFSAMA)

Takes in the numbers as digit arrays.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
e19AdES
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLUw0tHVNcgyE8qOCCXdHRhjqmOuY6hjrmsToK0aZAhjFQwCI2FqICAA)

Takes in the numbers as digit arrays.

##### Explanations

```python
z+19Ad  # Implicit input
z+      # Add the digits in the same positions together
    Ad  # Convert from
  19    # base-19
```

```python
e19AdES  # Implicit input
e    E   # Map over the input:
   Ad    #  Convert from
 19      #  base-19
      S  # Sum the list
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes

```
`@19!$_+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWKxIcDC0VVeK1IVyo6N5opWhDHVMdcx1DHfNYJR2laFMgyxgoYhGrFAtVBAA)

```
`@ Convert from base
19  19
!   zip
$    first input
_    second input
+    addition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>77</s> 72 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:sum(n*19**x for x,n in enumerate([*map(sum,zip(x,y))][::-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsMgEEDRq8xylAlEShcRchLrwhIlQp2IVUh6eWu2j//zVfeDHz2sr/5x6b05OOnS35aQpVqkPCEcZRhDZPDcki@uejQyuYwjo1/MOBYhrNF6UlaInkvkigGNotkSmJmeN/8B)

Not one of the shortest approaches, but it works.

*-5 bytes thanks to @ovs*

Comment: You can use `map` for 72 bytes: `enumerate([*map(sum,zip(x,y))][::-1])`.